# PowerPoint math equation compatibility issues

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-teams

I am creating PowerPoint files on macOS and then publish them for students in Microsoft Teams. Unfortuantly, there are recurring issues with math formulas not being displayed. I attach two screenshots to this thread. How would I report such a bug to Microsoft and what are my chances of this getting resolved quickly? Also, are there workarounds that I can use right now and which  keep the filetype (so no "export to PDF solution")? Why does this issue even appear? Is anyone aware of any official report to Microsoft about this that I can follow?

[image: original PowerPoint on macOS]

[image: portrayed PowerPoint in Microsoft Teams]

As far as I can tell, it is only an issue within the table and not within text for example. Funny enough, when I open the pptx file in Microsoft Teams, it displays the formulas in the table for a hot second before they vanish. So that makes me think it is an issue with the online version of PowerPoint and how it interprets the file?

Comment: make sure the text formulas are written in a simple font, e.g. arial, courier, consolas or similar - especially avoid using mathtype, formula editor or similar.

Comment: There is actually no way of changing Cambria Math to any other font once you are in formula mode. Avoiding formula mode is no solution for me. I want to be able to write fractions, etc.

Comment: Well, if you're in a "formula writing mode" then that is the probable cause for your trouble.  Look for any means to make it available when "publishing" in teams. Possibly use a screen grabber and create IMAGES of the formulas, to paste into the ppt you're using in teams.

Comment: I created a report on the official microsoft forum and a microsoft employee confirmed this being an issue and that they are aware of it: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/249666/powerpoint-math-equation-in-table-compatibility-is.html